# Length of Ed25519 signature

Tags: kotlin, cryptography, ecdsa, libsodium, ed25519

I am using lazysodium-android to generate keypairs and generating a signature using a message and privatekey as shown in the kotlin code below.

```
val pair = lazySodium.cryptoSignSeedKeypair(seed.seedBytes) 
println(pair.publicKey.asBytes.size) //32
println(pair.secretKey.asBytes.size) //64


val message = "helloWorld"
val signature = lazySodium.cryptoSignDetached(message, pair.secretKey)
println(signature.toByteArray().size) //128
```

But the signature should be 512 bits or 64 bytes. Why is it showing 128 bytes. Am I missing something?

Comment: [`cryptoSignDetached`](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/LazySodium.java) returns the result as hexadecimal string, i.e. each byte corresponds to two characters. [`toByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html) returns the characters in a [`ByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte-array/index.html) so that `size` is the number of characters. With 128 characters, the signature thus consists of 64 bytes [as expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Summary).

Comment: Ok. I now notice that asBytes return `[]byte` and toByteArray returns `ByteArray`. how can I get signature in `[]byte` type?

Comment: oh. my bad. I am trying to convert a hex string to byte array like I would convert a normal string. got it now.